# About Missing Remote File

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

When I run the pipeline, the Gitlab server alerts me that the remote YML file is missing, I used the Custom project CI config Path,(Setting => CI/CDL =>General pipelines=>Custom CI Config Path), below is my setup and error screen shot

[Custom CI Config Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbVxj.png)

[Error Screnn Shot:Missing File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeNLl.png)

Comment: The permissions of my YML remote repository are public. I can access this link through the browser's traceless mode or curl. However, when I use the custom CI config path, an error is reported

Comment: The path needs to be relative to your repository root - it cannot be an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

References to external YML are only supported in versions after Gitlab 12.6 after checking the official documentation

[image: Gitlab Official Introduction]